# Changing operator font for only one operator

Tags: fonts, math-operators, sans-serif

I want to declare a custom operator `op` that is supposed to use sans-serif font.
No other operator (`\sin` etc.) shall use sans-serif.

---

I tried to use `\DeclareMathOperator` which yields correct spacing but I seem unable to change the font for only this one operator.

I also tried a simple `\newcommand` which allows me to use sans-serif, but messes up the spacing.

[image]

How can I combine both approaches to get a sans-serif operator with correct operator spacing while not changing the font for all operators?

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{op}
\newcommand\opsans{\mathsf{op}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Correct spacing: \[a \op_k b\]
Wrong spacing: \[a \opsans_k b\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{op}
\DeclareMathOperator{\opp}{\mathsf{op}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\[a \op_k b\]

\noindent
\[a \opp_k b\]

\end{document}
```

Works fine here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `\mathop` TeX primitive declares operator. `\nolimits` primitive keeps the index and exponent at right side of the operator. So, you can define

```
\def\op{\mathop{operator-name}\nolimits}
```

The font selection (sans serif in math) depends on used format. For example in OpTeX with Unicode math we can define it like this:

```
\fontfam[lm]
\def\op{\mathop{\_sansvariables op}\nolimits}

$a \op_k b$

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of \hspace use \kern for better fixup inside the math

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{op}
\newcommand\opsans{\mathsf{op}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Correct spacing: [a \op_k b]
Wrong spacing: [a\hspace{0.5mm}\opsans_k\kern.5mm b]

\end{document}

Comment: Why, there is no need, use Denis' solution. Manually kerning is seldomly a good idea